# Pandas pivot or pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to take an excel data frame with the following format:

```
    DOW                 Location    7/30/2022   8/6/2022    8/13/2022   8/20/2022
    Volumes Saturday    North       33          32          29          24
    Volumes Saturday    South       34          17          30          28
    Volumes Sunday      North       40          57          25          28
    Volumes Sunday      South       47          38          32          45
    ACT Saturday        North       750         1060        1066        1082
    ACT Saturday        South       545         509         1306        1121
    ACT Sunday          North       801         860         572         795
    ACT Sunday          South       622         526         711         491
```

and have it output in this format:

```
DOW_Location            Location    Date        Volumes  ACT
Volumes Saturday North  North       7/30/2022   33       750
Volumes Sunday North    North       7/31/2022   40       801                
Volumes Saturday South  South       7/30/2022   34       545
Volumes Sunday South    South       7/31/2022   47       622
```

I figured I could do a `df.pivot()` after creating a unique index by combining `df['DOW'] + df['Location']` and strip out the Weekdays from `df['DOW']` to create a `df['Category']` column. My problem is that I have no idea how to fill the values in a pivot when the values span across multiple columns.

So I'm not sure what would fill the 'values' argument here:

```
df = df.pivot(index='DOW_Location', columns='Category', values=?)
```

If a pivot is not the ideal solution here, what is another way?

Comment: why the volume is 33 in your expected output and not 73?

Comment: Volume North Saturday (7/30/2022) is 33
Volume North Sunday (7/31/2022) is 40

Comment: your expected output doesn't have a day in it. please make expected output match the provided data?

Comment: @Naveed just edited it

Comment: you have volume and ACT in columns, how can you have the volume in the row? its contradicting, isn't it?

Comment: @Naveed yes I see that, I think that may have identified another issue in my first solution. Thank you, will have to figure out then make the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# split the DOW into columns
df[['col','day']]=df['DOW'].str.split(' ',expand=True)


# melt to bring the dates as rows
df2=df.melt(id_vars=['DOW','Location','col','day'], var_name='date')


#pivot and sum
(df2.pivot_table(index=['day','Location','date'],
                columns=['col'],aggfunc=sum)
    .reset_index())
```

```
    day     Location    date    value
col                 ACT     Volumes
0   Saturday    North   7/30/2022   750     33
1   Saturday    North   8/13/2022   1066    29
2   Saturday    North   8/20/2022   1082    24
3   Saturday    North   8/6/2022    1060    32
4   Saturday    South   7/30/2022   545     34
5   Saturday    South   8/13/2022   1306    30
6   Saturday    South   8/20/2022   1121    28
7   Saturday    South   8/6/2022    509     17
8   Sunday  North   7/30/2022   801     40
9   Sunday  North   8/13/2022   572     25
10  Sunday  North   8/20/2022   795     28
11  Sunday  North   8/6/2022    860     57
12  Sunday  South   7/30/2022   622     47
13  Sunday  South   8/13/2022   711     32
14  Sunday  South   8/20/2022   491     45
15  Sunday  South   8/6/2022    526     38
```

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: trying now, need to edit a few things for scale